# XML-Schema: Replace spaces

Tags: xml, regex, xsd, space

I'm writing a XMl schema to check an xml file. 
I want to add a restriction that checks, if the value contains spaces. If it does, they should be deleted.

e.g.: "Hello world" -> check -> "Helloworld"

If this isn't possible, I would like to throw an error when a space is found. I tried it with  but this only works if the value is "" or " " and not with "hello world".

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot replace characters, but a type does not accept spaces might bed declared like so:

```
<simpleType name="NoSpaceType">
    <restriction base="string">
        <pattern value="[^ ]+"/>
    </restriction>
</simpleType>
```

pattern is a regexp expression that you may change to better suite your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the whiteSpace facet to collapse multiple spaces to a single space (equivalent of XSLT's normalize-space() function, but not to remove all spaces.